# Using sbt-native-packager, how can I add a base directory inside my tar.gz file?

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

My project uses Play Framework 2.3.7 (that uses sbt 0.13.5, sbt-native-packager and Activator 1.2.12) and I'm generating a tar.gz file with

```
activator universal:package-bin
```

The generated tar.gz file include the directories (conf, bin, share, conf).

I need a base directory (/opt/my_application/) inside the tar.gz file, resulting in:

```
/opt/my_application/conf
/opt/my_application/bin
```

I tried several mappings combinations in my **build.sbt** from http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html, with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is add a sbt task to call a bash script:

```
lazy val generateTarGz = taskKey[Unit]("Generate tar.gz file")

generateTarGz := {
    "build.sh" !    
}
```

Then you call:

```
activator clean stage generateTarGz
```

The bash script will be called and generate a tar.gz with target/universal/stage/*.

Comment: You can all do this inside sbt. Using a shell script will exclude all windows users unless you provide a bat script as well. Also this makes the build more complicated than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to *remap* the existing `mappings in Universal`
as described [filter-remove-mappings examples](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#filter-remove-mappings). I should look
something like this

```
mappings in Universal := {
    val universalMappings = (mappings in Universal).value
    val appName = name.value
    universalMappings map {
        case (file, path) =>  (file, s"$appName/$path")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code, that's almost it. Changing the file path to "/opt/myapp/$path" makes the path inside the tar.gz to "/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/opt/myapp/$path". The problem here is the app name and version being the base directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/276) for this with a workaround.